# How to get the status of people by using email Ids from Skype for business using vba/ui-path/rest api?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, skype-for-business, uipath

I have a list of ~7000 people(in excel) with their details like email, alias etc. I want to figure out those people who have left the organization.

So, I'm looking for a way to fetch the status of each person from skype for business e.g if the status is unknown/ presence unknown - will mark them as left.

**Is it possible to fetch the status of a person from skype for business using VBA/UI-path or js/rest API?**

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to check the LDAP  / AD status?

Comment: If it's Skype For Business then it should be tied into your Active Directory. You could then just fire some queries at Active Directory or Scrape out active users.

Comment: Thank you for the response! quick ask, could you please share the process or documentation link from where I can read about the above-mentioned process? would be a great help!